# Rails link_to doesn't accept inside ruby code

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a problem with my Rails app. I want to link

```
<h1><%= news.title %></h1>
```

like this. But instead of HTML tag "a", I want to use link_to.

```
<a href="trainers-single.html" class="postTitle"><h1><%= news.title %></h1></a>
```

Like:

```
<%= link_to "<h1><%= news.title %></h1>", news, :class => "postTitle" %>
```

But it doesn't accept it. What is the correct way of showing it?

Answer (score 4):

Just use:

```
<h1><%= link_to news.title, news, :class => "postTitle" %></h1>
```

Comment: This solution doesn't give a link to h1, it creates a h1 linked that has a link. Like: <h1><a href="blabla">LINK</a></h1> instead of <a href="blabla"><h1>LINK</h1></a>

Answer (score 1):

```
<%= link_to news, :class => "postTitle" do %>
  <h1><%= news.title %></h1> 
<% end %>
```

I suppose you also can use

```
<%= link_to "<h1>#{ news.title }</h1>".html_safe, news, :class => "postTitle" %>
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the `a` tag outside the `h1` tag do:

```
<%= 
link_to news, class: "postTitle" do
%>
  <h1><%= news.title %></h1>
<%
end
%>
```